# 返金時のCreateRecurringPaymentsProfileのIPN通知について

Tags: paypal

初回決済（即時支払い、定期支払い）が成功した後に、DoExpressCheckoutPaymentのIPN通知でpayment_status=Pendingになった場合、CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileのIPN通知には影響するのでしょうか？また、DoExpressCheckoutPaymentのIPN通知がpayment_status=Reversedになった場合は、CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileのIPN通知も連動するのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DoExpressCheckoutPaymentのpayment_statusがCreateRecurringPaymentProfileのIPN通知に影響することはありませんよ。

Comment: 影響しないんですね。解答ありがとうございます。